# Alter existing Column Identity From No To yes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Term need a script to change an exist column called TermID identity specification from No to yes.
Any recommended script without use the column proprieties.

Comment: drop and re-create the column

Comment: there no another way for do that ?

Comment: No, there is no other way. You cannot "add" the `Identity` feature to an existing column, nor can you remove it from one. You can only specify the identity feature when you **create** (add) a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the new ID column, copy data from the old column, delete the old column:

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'MyTable.TermID' , 'TermID_OLD', 'COLUMN'

ALTER TABLE MyTable
  ADD TermID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON

UPDATE MyTable
SET TermID = TermID_OLD

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF

ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN TermID_OLD
```